# registering for NSNotification crashing my application?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, nsnotifications

i am playing a movie using **MPMovieplayerViewController** and i want to register for notifications when the movie stops...i am using the following code to use **NSNotification** but my application is crashing when the movie stops...i have used the **NSNotification** in same way earlier when it executed fine.. any idea regarding what i am doing wrong??

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(playbackFinishedCallback:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:movie];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) 
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                           object:nil];
- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification
{

NSLog(@"moviePlayBackDidFinish");
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *movie = [notification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                              object:movie];


[self performSelector:@selector(stopRecording) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];

}

-(void)playbackFinishedCallback:(NSNotification *)notification{

MPMoviePlayerViewController *movie = [notification object];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                              object:movie];

NSLog(@"playbackFinishedCallback:");


[self performSelector:@selector(stopRecording) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];


}
```

in my AppDelegate class i have registered like this

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    


[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) 
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                           object:nil];



// Override point for customization after application launch.

// Add the navigation controller's view to the window and display.
[window addSubview:navigationController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}

- (void)dealloc {

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                              object:nil];

[navigationController release];
[window release];
[super dealloc];
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's that :

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                     selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) 
                                         name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                       object:nil];
```

In the line above you pass a nil object and in the method you try to get it :

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *movie = [notification object];
```